# Code splitting a react-admin app with a bundle before and after login

Tags: reactjs, code-splitting, dynamic-import, react-admin

Consider the react-admin app like presented below. I'm planning to code split in a way that everything in `'./posts'` and `'./users'` is only loaded after the user is logged in.

I plan to use the [dynamic import() syntax](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-dynamic-import/) that I can use so that [webpack automatically starts code-splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import) the app.

The problem I see is that all app components are imported with the definition of the app. A dynamic import of stuff in `'./posts'` and `'./users'` would not be split since it's imported at the app itself.

How can I setup and split this codebase so that stuff in `'./posts'` and `'./users'` is loaded only after the user has logged in?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import { Login } from 'ra-ui-materialui';
import { authProvider, dataProvider, i18nProvider } from './providers';
// vvv - to be loaded after the user has logged in 
import { PostList, PostEdit, PostCreate, PostIcon } from './posts';
import { UserList, UserEdit, UserCreate, UserIcon } from './users';
// ∧∧∧

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Admin
                title="MyApp"
                loginPage={Login}
                dataProvider={dataProvider}
                authProvider={authProvider}
                i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
            >
                <Resource
                    name="posts"
                    list={PostList}
                    edit={PostEdit}
                    create={PostCreate}
                    icon={PostIcon}
                />
                <Resource
                    name="users"
                    list={UserList}
                    edit={UserEdit}
                    create={UserCreate}
                    icon={UserIcon}
                />
            </Admin>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your "posts" and "users" components with react-loadable.

My recent usages (work with pure react-router app and react-admin app!)

```
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const AsyncCrontabList = Loadable({
    loader: () => import('./containers/Crontab/CrontabList'),
    loading: Loading
});

<Resource name="crontabs" context="interval"
                              options={{ label: 'Crontabs', group: 'Automation' }}    icon={<TimerIcon/>}
                              list={AsyncCrontabList}
                              create={AsyncCrontabCreate}
                              edit={AsyncIntervalEdit}/>
```

After that, I can see components are chunked in F12 - Debug.
As I know, these chunks would be loaded (actually imported) when we navigate to the correct path. And with react-admin, a resource is identified and navigated by a name, so when you apply the loadable method here, it would work! That's my use cases.

Comment: That looks like it. When I have time to test this, I'll probably accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood you want to show posts and users only after the login so something you can do is wrap the other to components in a condition using a state variable and pass a function to your `Admin` component and call it when login is successful something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource } from 'react-admin';
import { Login } from 'ra-ui-materialui';
import { authProvider, dataProvider, i18nProvider } from './providers';
// vvv - to be loaded after the user has logged in 
import { PostList, PostEdit, PostCreate, PostIcon } from './posts';
import { UserList, UserEdit, UserCreate, UserIcon } from './users';
// ∧∧∧

class App extends Component {
   state:{
     loggedIn: false,
          }
    onLoginSuccess(){
     this.setState({loggedIn: true});
     }
    render() {
        return (
            <Admin
                title="MyApp"
                loginPage={Login}
                onLoginSuccess={this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this)}
                dataProvider={dataProvider}
                authProvider={authProvider}
                i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
            >
               {(this.state.loggedIn) && 
                  <Resource
                    name="posts"
                    list={PostList}
                    edit={PostEdit}
                    create={PostCreate}
                    icon={PostIcon}
                />
                <Resource
                    name="users"
                    list={UserList}
                    edit={UserEdit}
                    create={UserCreate}
                    icon={UserIcon}
                />
             }
            </Admin>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

or the better way might be to create a separates routes file and handle 
    all this logic there

Comment: What I meant had not so much to do about showing (yeah that too), but more about loading. I don't want the javascript stuff in `'./posts'` and `'./users'` to be loaded in the browser at all before the user is logged in.